# How to navigate between primefaces selectOneMenu using ENTER Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

how to stimulate enter key to work as the tab key to navigate between primefaces selectOneMenu components, if is there any solution using javascript

Comment: what you have tried, just showcase that first, for the better idea what you require.

Comment: i don't really understand your meaning

Comment: I rolled back your 'solution'. They do not belong in questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not to use javascript with the jsf html tag, try this code it worked for me

```
 function funcionName() {
    document.getElementById("form:id").focus();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked for me, i just updated my question if anybody could be interessed about the answer, you made my day